# grayscale histogram with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, grayscale

I'm new to gnuplot and I want to draw a triple histogram for a set of data of any length.
Here is my code but the line `set palette gray` seems to have no effect -- everything is still in RGB. What am I missing here?

```
set terminal pdf enhanced
set output 'out.pdf'

set palette gray

set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1

set style fill solid 1
set auto x
set yrange [0:*]
plot 'in.dat' using 2:xtic(1) title col, \
        '' using 3:xtic(1) title col, \
        '' using 4:xtic(1) title col
```

Answer (score 5):

The `set palette` command influences only images, pm3d surfaces and if used explicitely with e.g. `linecolor palette`.

The terminal option `monochrome` also doesn't help you, because that sets the color of all lines to black and uses different dash patterns.

You can e.g. redefine the color of the linetypes:

```
set linetype 1 lc rgb 'black'
set linetype 2 lc rgb '#555555'
set linetype 3 lc rgb '#999999'
plot 'in.dat' u 2:xtic(1) t col, '' u 3 t col, '' u 4 t col
```

Note, that `reset` doesn't revert this line type changes. For this you must restart gnuplot.

Alternatively, you could also use `set terminal pdf monochrome` and `set style fill pattern`.